# How to comapare two different colomns of two different table in sql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I use this code to fetch the data from table ‘empdet’ and insert them to Another table ‘check update’.
I want to compare two colomns of these two tables and echo the different colomn form the table ‘empdet’

ss.php

```
  <?php
 require "init.php";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM empdet";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Employeeid: " . $row["Employeeid"]. " " . $row["last_update"]. "<br>";
                $sqls = "INSERT INTO Check_Update (Employeeid, Schduleid, Check_update)
                VALUES ('".$row[Employeeid]."', '". $row[id]."', '".$row[last_update]."')";
                echo $sqls.'<br>';      
                $res =$con->query($sqls);

    }

}
 else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$con->close();
   ?>
```

DATABASE TABLE
[image: TABLE 1 empdet]
[image: TABLE 2 check updaate]

For example.
I want to compare the colomn  ’last_update ’ of table ‘empdet’ with colomn ‘check_update’ of table ‘check update’ so that I can find the difference between these two colomns, and I can put the row in echo of the table ‘empdate’.
Like, there is a change in last two rows of ‘empdat’ i.e ’last_update’ , so when I compare with the colomn ‘ check_update’ it should echo the last two row of the ‘empdat’ and also it should update the last two rows of  ‘check_update’ colomn.
My question is
1)how to compare two colomns of two tables?
2)how to put them echo?
3)how to update the ‘check_update’ colomn after it finds the difference?

I am a beginner to mysql queries, can any one help me to do this?

Comment: look at this answer hope it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019325/php-compare-column-values-and-edit-database-accordingly

Comment: i want to compare two tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
require "init.php";
$sql = "select e.id ,e.Employeeid,e.last_update from empdel AS e inner join Check_Update.* AS c on c.Scheduleid = e.id
where e.last_update != c.Check_Update";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
            echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Employeeid: " . $row["Employeeid"]. " " . $row["last_update"]. "<br>";

            $sqls =  "update Check_Update set Check_Update = '".$row['last_update']."' where Scheduleid = '".$row["id"]."' "
            echo $sqls.'<br>';      
            $res =$con->query($sqls);
    }
}
else 
{ 
   echo "0 results";
}

$con->close();
```